# PhantomJS passing variable to page.open

Tags: variables, url, phantomjs, argument-passing

I need to capture an URL on one page and then open the target. What's the most elegant solution? The code below doesn't work, because the variable *url* is basically local.

```
function() {
  page.open("https://www.google.com/blah");
},
function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    var url=document.getElementById('link42')[0]; //URL captured
  });
},
//opening the target 
function() {
  page.open(url);
},
function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].outerHTML);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably make it *global*. You just have to mind how you get the url out of the page context. It is not possible to return DOM elements, but you can return everything that is JSON serializable.

Quote from [`page.evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

```js
var url;

// function chainer
function() {
  page.open("https://www.google.com/blah");
},
function() {
  url = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById('link42').href; // href captured
  });
},
//opening the target 
function() {
  page.open(url);
}
```

`getElementById` only returns a single element, so you can't use `[0]`.